# Wordpress Featured Image linking to original image

Tags: regex, wordpress-theming

the featured image always links to the single post. How can I link the featured image to the big image so it can be opend in a fancyBox or something.

Can anyone help me, to do this via the functions.php. Maybe it is something with regular expressions deleting the standard post link and than replace it with the attached image link.

Thanks for help,
Denis

Answer (score 0):

You can use this hook for get full image.

```
the_post_thumbnail('full');
```